# Prevent sshfs reconnecting

Tags: ssh, sshfs

I use sshfs to connect to a remote server. When my computer goes to sleep or internet drops, sshfs tries to reconnect when the connection comes back, but does not ask me for a password. Because of this, the reconnect fails, and after several attempts my IP address is blocked indefinitely from connecting to the server (until I convince them to unblock me). Overall this is completely untenable. How can I prevent sshfs from reconnecting? I am not using any of the ServerAliveInterval, ServerAliveCountMax, or -o reconnect options.

Comment: I have had the same issue in the past! As a first check have you made sure you are omitting the -reconnect option when you run sshfs? Could you please share the sshfs command you are running?

Comment: I am just calling sshfs username@server:/homefolder/ ~/sshfs